# GTK passing structure to callback function in C

Tags: c, callback, gtk, signals

Still new in GTK, now trying to work on event-driven programming and stuck in weird situation: there is no problem to send scalar items to callback function, but then it comes to sending struct to it, still receiving the error with no idea what's wrong.

Sample "stub" code is:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void messageup();
void exiting();

struct data{
    char *message;
    GtkWidget *window;
};


int main (int   argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkBuilder      *builder; 
  GtkWidget       *window;
  GtkWidget       *entryMainValue;
  struct data d;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new ();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "samplemain.ui", NULL);
  window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "applicationwindow1"));
  entryMainValue = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "entryMainValue"));
  g_signal_connect (window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (exiting), NULL);
  d.message = "message\n";
  d.window = window;
  g_signal_connect (entryMainValue, "activate", G_CALLBACK (messageup), d);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));
  gtk_widget_show (window);                
  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}

void messageup(GtkWidget *entryMainValue, gpointer user_data){

    struct data *d = (struct data*) user_data;


    g_print("Hello World!\n%s\n", user_data.message);
}

void exiting()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Now having the error looking like this:

```
gtkbldprj.c: In function ‘main’:
gtkbldprj.c:29:3: error: incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘g_signal_connect_data’
   g_signal_connect (entryMainValue, "activate", G_CALLBACK (messageup), d);
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from gtkbldprj.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gsignal.h:388:9: note: expected ‘gpointer’ but argument is of type ‘struct data’
 gulong  g_signal_connect_data        (gpointer    instance,
         ^
gtkbldprj.c: In function ‘messageup’:
gtkbldprj.c:42:41: error: request for member ‘message’ in something not a structure or union
  g_print("Hello World!\n%s\n", user_data.message);
                                         ^
gtkbldprj.c:39:15: warning: unused variable ‘d’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct data *d = (struct data*) user_data;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try with a pointer instead of struct ?

Comment: Pass the address of `d`, i.e. `&d`, instead of `d`.

Comment: Good point! Now how to parse the structure correctly on callback function side? :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several C errors here.
GTK allows you on some functions to pass a `gpointer user_data`. A `gpointer` is just a `void *` (ie. a pointer to *something*). If you want to pass a structure, you need the address of the structure, not the structure itself. That is called *passing by address*, as opposed to *passing by value*.

So, instead of:

```
g_signal_connect (entryMainValue, "activate", G_CALLBACK (messageup), d);
```

write:

```
g_signal_connect (entryMainValue, "activate", G_CALLBACK (messageup), &d);
```

Then, when you're in the callback, the `user_data` parameter you receive is a pointer to *something*. You need to transform it into a pointer to your structure.

So instead of:

```
void messageup(GtkWidget *entryMainValue, gpointer user_data)
{
    struct data *d = (struct data*) user_data;
    g_print("Hello World!\n%s\n", user_data.message);
}
```

You need to access the *message* field using a pointer of the right type (`d`, not `user_data`), and use the `->` operator as you're accessing the structure through a pointer:

```
void messageup(GtkWidget *entryMainValue, gpointer user_data)
{
    struct data *d = user_data;
    g_print("Hello World!\n%s\n", d->message);
}
```

You seem confused about pointers, so give a look at this nice [video about C pointers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E).

Another error is connecting to the `delete-event` to exit. This event is when you want to catch the fact that the user clicked on the exit cross of the window, or used Alt-F4 to exit, and you want to do something at that moment (show a confirmation popup, save some data). So there's no need to connect there, the destruction will happen (that uses the `destroy` signal).

So **instead** of connecting to the `delete-event` signal, connect to the `destroy` signal, and in response to this signal, exit the GTK+ main loop:

```
g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
```

Comment: First thank you for detailed answer! Now about some problems still exist: still got empty message box displayed. Also confused about "useless" delete-event: I listen to window closing to ensure application is terminated on closing it, otherwise got headless app hanging somewhere in RAM.

Comment: For the empty window, it's probably because you call `gtk_widget_show` instead of `gtk_widget_show_all` (which will recursively call `gtk_widget_show` on the widget children).

Comment: About the `delete-event`: signals have a default behavior, which does the right thing. The default callback for this event returns `FALSE` to propagate the event further. The returned value will determine if the `destroy` signal handler will be called. And by default, this is the case, so you have nothing to do to destroy the object yourself.

Comment: Bit late, but I wasn't clear enough: use the `destroy` signal instead of `delete-event`, and use `gtk_main_quit` as a callback.