# How to correctly pass a struct to g_signal_connect in GTK4 in C?

Tags: c, callback, gtk, signals, gtk4

I'm trying to pass the address of a struct to the gpointer data argument of g_signal_connect such that the callback function can print the int members of the struct when a button is clicked. I'm new to GTK and am confused as to why it's not working.

I was expecting the print functions in the callback function (print_location) to correctly print 1 and 5 but instead they print 0 and 0. I used the top answer in [GTK passing structure to callback function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669855/gtk-passing-structure-to-callback-function-in-c) as a reference but it doesn't appear to be working here.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct data{
        int row;
    int column;
};

void print_location(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    struct data *d = user_data;
    printf("clicked\n");
        // these do not print as expected
    printf("row: %d\n", d->row);
    printf("col: %d\n", d->column);
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *grid;
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  grid = gtk_grid_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), grid);


  // example row and column data
  struct data d;
  d.row = 1;
  d.column = 5;
  // sanity check
  struct data *c = &d;
  printf("row: %d, col: %d\n", c->row, c->column); // this prints as expected
  // end of sanity check
  GtkWidget *button;
  button = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  
  // passing the struct here
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_location), &d);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.test", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Again I'm new to GTK and not too experienced in C in general so any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `g_signal_connect( .... &d);` What do you expect to be stored at the location where `&d` points to after that function returns? Your variable `d` is a local variable in `activate`. It's lifetime is over after the function returns. You need to provide some memory that will still be valid when the callback function is called. You can make it a `static` variable in that function or you can use a global variable or dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks, adding static fixed it. I obviously need to revise scope.

Comment: Glad it helped. Close, but wrong. ;) Lifetime is what you need to revise, not scope.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered here.

[unable to add label to box by the click of a button gtk4 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77621085/22768315)

```
typedef struct {
  GtkWidget* prompt;
  GtkWidget* box;
} MyWidgets;


// Create a data structure to hold multiple pieces of data
    static MyWidgets widgets;
    MyWidgets *widgets_ptr =&widgets ;
    widgets_ptr->box = box;
    widgets_ptr->prompt = prompt;

// When the button is clicked, passed as an argument
g_signal_connect((GtkButton*)button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_clicked),widgets_ptr);
```

I hope I could help.